# Unable to load swf file in FlexPaper

Tags: flexpaper

I am trying to use FlexPaper to display Pdf files. I convert pdf to swf also and load it in flexpaper control by pressing button. It show 100% and docoument is unable to display in FlexPaper control.

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myViewer.SwfFile="test1.swf";
}

<s:Button x="84" y="491" label="Button"  click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
<flexpaper:FlexPaperViewer id="myViewer" x="10" y="26" width="892" height="284"  >
</flexpaper:FlexPaperViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working for me. I think the problem may be test1.swf file.

Please refer the below url and convert pdf to swf properly.

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/docs_converting.jsp

If u have any problem ask me.